# Chrome not loading page, safari does

Tags: http, google-chrome, safari

I was wondering if anyone can help me out. I've got a page that shows about 260 images so it obviously takes a long time to load. I've noticed a lot of the time in Chrome it takes **too** long to load, and by too long I mean it appears to be unresponsive.

Safari on the other hand seems to load the page up pretty quickly.

So I am left here wondering is there something that exists in the lifecycle of a chrome http request that would be trying to pre-load the images or something to that effect which is causing the delay.

Both browsers are working from an empty cache.

Can anyone enlighten me!

Comment: Are you able to change the number of images? Maybe you wanna try with e.g. 50, 100, 150 with both the browsers as well, just to make sure that it is in fact a delay due to the number of pictures.

Answer (score 0):

The network tab on the chrome developer tools will let you see the order the images are loading in, and the average time fetching each from the server.  I've seen issues where a certain higher res image can cause a browser to stutter a bit when rendering the page (usually IE :s), so this might help you pinpoint if its a particular image causing the issue.
http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html